# How can I get an asymptotic lower bound for a sum of terms, some of which are negative?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I'm trying to find a big-theta estimate for
$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(3\cdot 4^i + 2\cdot3^i-i^{19} +20\right)$$
From what I understand, if not for the $-i^{19}$ term, I could reason as follows:

First, since a sum of finitely many terms is bounded from above by (the the maximal term) $\times$ (the number of terms), we have $f(n) = O(3\cdot 4^n \cdot 4n) = O(n4^n)$.

Second, since
$$\textbf{Fact: } \text{the sum of finitely many nonnegative terms is bounded from below by (any one of the terms) } \times \text{ (the number of terms)}$$

we have $f(n) = \Omega(3\cdot 4^n \cdot 4n) = \Omega(n4^n)$.

Therefore, $f(n) = \Theta(n4^n)$.

Now since there's a negative term $-i^{19}$, I technically can't apply the $\textbf{Fact}$ in the second part of my argument. But since $i^{19}$ is so small compared to $4^i$, this intuitively shouldn't be a problem. So my question is: Is there a generalization of the $\textbf{Fact}$ that says something to the effect of: the sum of finitely many terms in which the only negative terms are significantly smaller in magnitude than at least one of the positive terms, is bounded from below by (any one of the positive terms) $\times$ (the number of terms)?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm very new to math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to prove that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $n^{19} < 3^n$. This follows for instance from the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{19}}{3^n}=0$.

Therefore, for every $n>n_0$ we have $2\cdot 3^n - n^{19} > 3^n$, from which your required lower bound follows:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 3\cdot 4^i +2\cdot 3^i - i^{19}+20 > \sum_{i=1}^n 3\cdot 4^i + 3^i +20$$
and apply the fact you relied on in just the same way as in your question.

Comment: Could you explain why the lower bound follows?

Comment: @user236343 I edited to add more detail, is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @user236343 Note though that there's something I don't get in your $\Omega(n\cdot 4^n)$ estimate. We can say the sum is larger than the largest element i.e. we get $\Omega(4^n)$ but I don't see why $\Omega(n\cdot 4^n)$ would follow.